# Is internet explorer the only browser that allows local path inclusion for file uploads?

Tags: html, security, browser

I'm creating a web application with a very limited set of users who want to be able to upload local file paths through the use of the file input type.  A healthy bit of research has demonstrated that this is typically undesirable and can be a pretty massive security hole if misused.  Despite that fact, internet explorer--version 11, at least--allows users to configure their browsers such that the genuine local path is included in uploads instead of the fake path that other browsers use.

While I realize the security implications of allowing the full local path to be disclosed, I was curious if it was possible to override the fake path protection that other major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari) provide.  I don't want to enforce internet explorer use if I don't have to, but if there is no other way, and this feature is that important, I suppose I will.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I guess the other side of this question is... Why does the server *need* this information?  You don't have to force IE usage on the client if you can de-couple the server from client-side file systems.

Comment: I was working on an intranet application once that also needed this path.  We worked around it by getting rid of the feature that used the full path, which was sad because it really was a handy feature.  I hope you can find a flag or switch to enable the full path for your users.

Comment: @David Users wish to upload the file paths where pertinent information on parts is stored.  The application aims to interface several different legacy applications which use the file paths (which are directories shared across the entire team) for various things.  I'm not certain I can get around the requirement, I'm unfamiliar with the use of the file paths in the other applications, but I know that I am using an old database that stores the file paths.

Comment: @Brad Ah, bummer.  Like I said, IE provides a setting that will allow for local path inclusion, but I haven't been able to find anything similar in Chrome or Firefox's settings.

Comment: @sheffware: Based on that description at least (which I may have easily misunderstood), it sounds like the path itself is a piece of information that needs to persist with some record.  If that's the case then a text input can be included whereby a path can be pasted in and saved.  That may require some re-thinking of the UI/UX of course.

Comment: @David Haha, yea that's actually what I have implemented right now,  but there has been an overwhelming desire for using the browser's built-in file input button.  I am fairly new to web dev., so I thought I'd ask before telling the users that they either have to use internet explorer, or they have to copy paste the path into a text input.  We've been using the application for a couple of months and this is one of the only complaints I've had about it.